# jquery how do I get an imgs src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery and I have some code setup like so

```
$('.gallery img').click(function(){
    $('#gal_img').html('<img src=""/>');
});
```

this has a lot of other things running that dont matter, but I want it to get the img src from the ".gallery img" is placed into the new img. I have multiple images inside the .gallery div

Answer (score 6):

You can use either **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**:

```
$('.gallery img').click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#gal_img').html('<img src="' + src + '"/>');
});
```

or **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** to get the `src` attribute of an image:

```
$('.gallery img').click(function(){
    var src = $(this).prop('src');
    $('#gal_img').html('<img src="' + src + '"/>');
});
```

---

As @Vision suggestion you can also use pure javascript `this.src`

```
$('.gallery img').click(function () {
    $('#gal_img').html('<img src="' + this.src + '"/>');
});
```

Comment: No need to overcomplicate the things. `this.src` is the fastest solution.

Comment: Actually, I've wrote it as a suggestion beside my answer but end up deleted it because I scare OP apply it in the wrong way :P

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

```
$('img').prop('src')
```

[Sample JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/caVYd/132/)

Or else you may simply try this:

```
$('.gallery img').click(function(){
    $('#gal_img').html('<img src="' + this.src + '"/>');
});
```

Comment: He want it to get the img src from the ".gallery img" it is not an right answer

Comment: @sudhar And using `prop` is the best method to go here. This answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do just like this (the fastest solution):

```
$('.gallery img').click(function(){
    $('#gal_img').html('<img src="' + this.src + '"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.gallery img').click(function(){
   var img = $('<img />', {'src' : this.src});
   $('#gal_img').html(img);
});
```